# Module not found: Can't resolve 'formik' in 'C:\Live projects\New folder (2)\src\_metronic\partials\modals\create-app'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

```html
"dependencies": {
    "@formatjs/intl-pluralrules": "^4.0.28",
    "@formatjs/intl-relativetimeformat": "^9.1.7",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.3",
    "@popperjs/core": "~2.10.1",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "apexcharts": "^3.27.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.7.2",
    "chart.js": "^3.3.2",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "del": "^6.0.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "line-awesome": "^1.3.0",
    "lint-staged": "^11.0.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "1.6.2",
    "nouislider": "^15.2.0",
    "object-path": "^0.11.5",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "prism-react-renderer": "^1.2.1",
    "prism-themes": "^1.7.0",
    "prismjs": "^1.23.0",
    "qs": "6.10.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.3.9",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.1.0",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-inlinesvg": "^2.3.0",
    "react-intl": "^5.20.4",
    "react-is": "^17.0.2",
    "react-query": "^3.34.12",
    "react-router-dom": "6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "react-table": "^7.7.0",
    "react-topbar-progress-indicator": "^4.1.0",
    "rtlcss-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.6",
    "sass": "1.32.1",
    "socicon": "^3.0.5",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
```

```js
./src/_metronic/partials/modals/create-app/Main.tsx
Module not found: Can't resolve 'formik' in 'C:\Live projects\New folder (2)\src\_metronic\partials\modals\create-app'
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'
```

```html
import {useFormik} from 'formik'
 "formik": "^2.2.9",
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coFI2.png)./src/_metronic/partials/modals/create-app/Main.tsx

When i did use this ***yarn add formik or npm install --save formik*** command, I was after install,I got  "formik": "^2.2.9",But i did not solve above issue, Why it's happening error i did not get,I was tried ***remove node modules and package lock json*** but no use, I hope please be can you help for me on this issue?

Comment: Try deleting the node modules and package-lock.json then redo yarn install

Comment: Yes, i already did it, But not use again throw same error

Comment: To confirm: When you removed node_modules and package-lock.json you did remember to run `npm install` to get them back right?

Comment: Yes, I got it already thanks for all , I seems like a kindly helped me, I remember this moment for ever.

Answer (score 0):

***To confirm***: When you removed ***node_modules and package-lock.json*** you did remember to run ***npm install*** to get them back right? by ***apokryfos***.

Try deleting the ***node modules and package-lock.json*** then redo ***yarn install***!->by
***Dharmik Patel***
Both are helpful for fixed issue ***this credit goes to them only***, thanks for all.